# How to create diagonal gradient from corner to corner?

Tags: html, css

I have columns with gradients.  Need create a gradient that will start from top right corner to bottom left corner, but corners of a gradient are clipped.
It looks ugly and and corners of gradients are not linked. I tried use background image but it is bad working on mobile devices.

```
  <section class="slider">
    <div class="container slider-menu">

        <div class="col-lg-5ths col-md-5ths col-sm-5ths col-xs-4"><img src="http://rustypepper.me/production/img/icon-2.png" alt="Шарики" class="img-responsive">
          <p>

            Lorem <br> Ipsum
          </p>
        </div>

       // ........ 14 same columns

  </section>

.slider-menu div {
  background: #006bac;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  height: 240px; }

  .slider-menu div img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999; }

.slider-menu div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;

  background: black;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, white 51%, black 51%, white 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, black), color-stop(51%, white), color-stop(51%, black), color-stop(100%, white));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, white 51%, black 51%, white 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, white 51%, black 51%, white 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, white 51%, black 51%, white 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, white 51%, black 51%, white 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 );
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */ }

.slider-menu img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto; }

.slider-menu p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 20px; }
```

http://codepen.io/lifetowin/pen/PqByRK/

Comment: Couldn't you just apply a repeating gradient to the row container, instead of to each item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used 45 degree gradient so the height and the width of cells must be equal. Yours are not. So if you make the width and height are equal then it will be ok. And i changed the gradient stop %51 to %50

```
.slider-menu div {
  background: #006bac;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  height: 228px; }
  .slider-menu div img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999; }

.slider-menu div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,ffffff+52,000000+52,ffffff+100,000000+100,ffffff+100 */
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#000000+0,ffffff+51,000000+51,ffffff+100 */
  background: black;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, white 50%, black 50%, white 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%, black), color-stop(50%, white), color-stop(50%, black), color-stop(100%, white));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, white 50%, black 50%, white 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, white 50%, black 50%, white 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, white 50%, black 50%, white 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, white 50%, black 50%, white 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 );
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */ }



.slider-menu .row {
  padding: 0px; }

.slider-menu img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto; }

.slider-menu p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 20px; }


.col-xs-5ths,
.col-sm-5ths,
.col-md-5ths,
.col-lg-5ths {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px; }

.col-xs-5ths {
  width: 20%;
  float: left; }

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .col-sm-5ths {
    width: 20%;
    float: left; } }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-5ths {
    width: 20%;
    float: left; } }

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .col-lg-5ths {
    width: 20%;
    float: left; } }

@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .container {
    padding: 0px 15px; }
  .site-header .container {
    padding: 0px; }
  .slider-menu div {
    padding: 50px 0px 24px 0px; }
  .slider-menu p {
    font-size: 12px; }
  body {
    margin: 0 0 65px;
    /* bottom = footer height */ }
  .site-footer {
    height: 65px;
    padding: 0px 10px; }
    .site-footer p.pull-left {
      display: none; }
    .site-footer p.pull-right {
      float: left !important; }
  .list-image > div {
    margin-top: 15px; }
  .container > .navbar-collapse {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px; }
  .navbar-nav > li > p > a {
    color: #fff; }
  .navbar-nav {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 100%; }
    .navbar-nav li {
      width: 100%; }
    .navbar-nav .container {
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px; }
  .site-header .container > .navbar-header {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; } }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNjQmO

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what is needed. It is sad that all screens will not work correctly. If i set equal height and width to column,  text will not  placed in a column.

Answer (score 12):

An alternate solution is to set the angle with symbolics names

```
background: linear-gradient(to top right, black 0%, white 51%, black 51%, white 100%);
```

This way, the gradient will adapt itself to the container dimensions, instead of adapting the dimensions to the gradient angle